# An operation is currently performing on this storage account that requires exclusive access

Tags: azure, mocha.js, azure-storage

My requirement is to write test case for creating storage account for multiple api versions of storage account in azure. but got this error

> **An operation is currently performing on this storage account that requires exclusive access**.
>   but sometimes and intermittently test has been passed, so i want to know whats the root cause and how to fix this error.
>   My concern is what, Azure cant create multiple storage account in one go. or any other constraint from Azure that does not allow me to do this?

**My implementation:**
i have an one array which has several api-versions and below are my implementation,

```
let apiVersions =  ["2017-10-01", "2017-06-01", "2016-12-01", "2016-05-01", "2016-01-01"];

describe("put", function () {
  it("should create a storage account with storage account type, async () => {
    for (const apiVersion of apiVersions) {
      let location = 'uk south';
      let resourceGroupName = 'test';
      let storageAccountName = 'stacct';
      AzureAuthentication.StorageAccountApiVersion = apiVersion;
      // StorageAccount.FormatName(storageAccountName + apiVersion): this function will give me string without special charaters and spaces etc, e.g stacct20171001 
      await StorageAccount.CreateStorageAccount(resourceGroupName, location, StorageAccount.FormatName(storageAccountName + apiVersion), AzureAuthentication);
    }
  });
 });
```

any body face this error?

Comment: is this an integration test? if not just mock CreateStorageAccount

Comment: @Daniel, yes this is integration test.

Answer (score 1):

The error message could be due to missing specifications to your storage accounts that you'd like to create, checking your code, it doesn't specify the region where you want it to be created etc... check a sample on c# below:

```
 /* Include this "using" directive...
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent
*/

IStorageAccount storage = azure.StorageAccounts.Define(storageAccountName)
    .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
    .WithNewResourceGroup(rgName)
    .Create();
```

the full documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: i forgotten to mention location in above code but it has been provided to my actual test function, e.g. let location = "uk south"; etc

Comment: @Vinod I'm curious, have you tried a catch of the error then a retry? I've seen previous instances with the same error when creating parallel resources at the same time, creating a catch and retry in the code could fix this. I'll check internally if the limitation exist to the API and will get back to you by tomorrow.

Comment: yes one of solution is to create catch, but my concern is sometime its working, so is there any limitation from azure? yes it will help us to fix the issue.

Comment: detail error is, `{"code":"StorageAccountOperationInProgress","message":"An operation is currently performing on this storage account that requires exclusive access."}` because this error seems to be related to oeration is in progress", so it means that it requires some time for executing parallel operation, this is what i understood.

Comment: thank you for your prompt responses, another option can't we use await Promise.all()? Whats your opinion/suggestion?. i have tried with both solutions and both are working fine now. `await Promise.all(apiVersions.map(async apiVersion => {
            AzureAuthentication.StorageAccountApiVersion = apiVersion;
      await StorageAccount.CreateStorageAccount(resourceGroupName, location, StorageAccount.FormatName(storageAccountName + apiVersion), AzureAuthentication);
    }));`